# Using id that are comma separated sql

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

If you run this query

```
select 
    GROUP_CONCAT(p1.id) _fid,
    GROUP_CONCAT(p2.id) _mid,
    count(1)
from
    new_person as pb
        inner join
    new_person as p1 ON pb.father_id = p1.id
        inner join
    new_person as p2 ON pb.mother_id = p2.id
where
    (p1.last_name <> 'N.N.'
        and p1.last_name <> '')
        or (p2.last_name <> 'N.N.'
        and p2.last_name <> '')
group by p1.first_name , p1.last_name , p2.first_name , p2.last_name
having count(1) > 1;
```

you get a list of id back like this

```
'4676,6088,4804,4968,6554,5212,5504,5810,7298,7782,6970'
```

Is there a way so you can immediately use it in a other query or do you have to load it in php first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it in another query like so:

```
SELECT M.*, P.* FROM 
(  

  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(p1.id) _fid, GROUP_CONCAT(p2.id) _mid, count(1)
  FROM new_person AS pb
     INNER JOIN new_person AS p1 ON pb.father_id = p1.id
     INNER JOIN new_person AS p2 ON pb.mother_id = p2.id
  WHERE (
     p1.last_name <> 'N.N.'
     AND p1.last_name <> '')
     OR (p2.last_name <> 'N.N.'
     AND p2.last_name <> '')
  GROUP BY p1.first_name, p1.last_name, p2.first_name, p2.last_name
  HAVING COUNT(1) > 1

) AS M INNER JOIN new_person as p ON M._fid = p.id
```

Notice I added the entire query to the from statement with the alias as `M`.  You can then `JOIN` `M` to another table or do whatever you want from there.

Comment: thx for your answer and sorry for my late response 
if i do than and then run
select * from new_person as p inner join M on M._fid = p.id;
i get this error
Error Code: 1146. Table 'memorix.M' doesn't exist

Comment: I updated my answer with the join on `M` that I think you are after.

Comment: thx i dont have enoph points to vote you up else i would do that