# Storing Login details in a Database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, authentication, coldfusion

I have 3 user roles, ADMIN, GURDIAN, STUDENT. I have the GurdianProfile & StudentProfile tables linked using uniqueID's (i.e. GurdianID, StudentID). That is the link that connects the 'gurdianLogin' tables and 'studentLogin' tables.

My Question is: What is the standard way to structure a 'User Login' table? Should I use one single table to store different types of users (i.e. all the 3 types of users) ? Or is it better to use 3 different tables to use different type of users on a single database ?

What is the best-practice and strategy or recommendations ?

Note: I'm using ColdFusion, MySQL

Comment: suggest removing *"what is the best..."* from your question, could be interpreted as asking for an opinion. Though, i'm not sure if this question could be re-worded in a way that wasn't asking for an opinion.

Comment: It would likely be far simpler/easier on your authentication functionality if all authentication was done through a single user table. That doesn't necessarily mean you cant have the three other tables too if you wanted/needed them.

Comment: I designed the database with 3 User tables, but now struck trying to run 1 single query to check for the user and password, cause I have to run or merge 3 tables to get the right answer. I can use a single table, or write a query to capture the data from all the 3 tables. But I think I might have not planned well the User table designs. So it is in fact asking your opinions ... Hope the clarification helps clear the issue a bit more.

Comment: I would like to link you to an answer of mine on a similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26227103/sql-query-inner-join-tables-print-to-html-select-tag/26227608#26227608

Comment: Flagged to move this to dba.stackexchange since this is really a question about database structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a single logon point, I would see having credentials spread across 3 different tables as a flaw because if you ever added a 4th user type, you would then have to update your login system to incorporate the new user type. So, i would go with having a single user table, and then if you need separate tables for your guardian/student/admin profiles, link them to the user table.

```
_User_
id
email
username
password (this better not store the password in plain text..)

_GuardianProfile_
id
userid (links to user table)
(GuardianProfile fields)

_StudentProfile_
id
userid (links to user table)
(StudentProfile fields)

_AdminProfile_
id
userid (links to user table)
(AdminProfile fields)
```

If the columns in the three profile types are the same, it might make sense to condense that to one table with a type column.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Just need one more clarification. Why should we use a 'ID' on these 4 Tables ? Already the 'userNames' will be unique and would that not be sufficient? And again I already have 'studentID', 'gurdianID' which will store its own ID's. But for the 'User' table, simply the username, password & role would be enough would it ? Or is there a good use for the 'ID' columns as well ? And should these 'ID's be identical to each other in some way ?

Comment: Well, for example, Id in the user table is the userid, and the id in each of the profile tables is the index for each of those tables. It isn't required, just something I usually do with my tables. I'm sure there's some reason for it, I just don't know what said reason is.

Answer (score 0):

I use one table to store login details - userid (primary key), salt, passwords, usernames, email addresses.

I authenticate against this table.  I then use other tables linked by the userid to store contact information or other important data.

For restricting access to certain parts of the site I create other tables such as user, adimn, superadmin and store the userid's.  I then test against the desired table to see if the userid is present and thus determine access to a page/area.