# looping over a list with multiple and selected the selected ones

Tags: coldfusion

I'm working on code where I am getting two lists. I'm trying to use those lists to pre-select items in select box having the "multiple" attribute. However, I am unable to maintain the selections.

**Code:**

```
<select name="sbbox" id="sbbox" class="can" multiple>
  <cfloop list="#lstFinds#" index="k" delimiters=",">
    <option value="#k#" <cfif #listfindnocase(k,getproducts.ptype)#>selected</cfif>>#k#</option>
  </cfloop> 
</select>
```

**Sample values:**

- `lstFinds = abc,xyz`
- `getproducts.ptype` also contains values like `abc,xyz`

I want to keep both selected, if both values exists for the user. If one exists, keep one selected. If none are selected, keep none.

I also tried using `listContains`, but it did not work.

**Transferred from pastebin linkL**

The `ptype` values are coming as comma separated in the database ie "abc,wed,mon,def". Whatever those values are, I need to match and selected the ones which have the same value in the listFind. I hope I made it clearer.

```
<cfset lstFinds = 'abc,xyz,def,www,kkr,mon,tue,wed'>

<cfquery name="getproducts" datasource="cdfg">
        select ptype
         from
        mytable  
        where
        ID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#id#">
</cfquery>


<select name="sbbox" id="sbbox" class="can" multiple>
  <cfloop list="#lstFinds#" index="k" delimiters=",">
    <option value="#k#" <cfif #listfindnocase(k,getproducts.ptype)#>selected</cfif>>#k#</option>
  </cfloop>
</select>
```

Comment: Switch your arguments around for listFind. The list is the first argument. When in doubt check the documentation

Comment: i did not get what exactly you trying to say, can you please clarify

Comment: Your listFind function should have the list as the first argument and the value to find as the second

Comment: changed it, but that does not solve the issue, i am facing

Comment: What is the value of K in each iteration?

Comment: k is the value of the first loop items - abc,xyz,def -

Comment: both can have the same values depending upon suppose lstFinds has [abc,xyz,def] and the getproducts.ptype has [def,abc], so i want the two to be selected

Comment: Could you please elaborate the question then? Show us some real data from the ptype field and what lstFinds would really contain for the same row. Something like http://pastebin.com/XrhDjCEv (I do understand that lstFinds isn't a column name), but this would still be a good way to present a snapshot of real data to us. You don't need to put it in a pastebin, I merely did because comments don't support formatting.

Comment: i am editing my question: Please check #update1

Comment: here is the pasbin : http://pastebin.com/tQHVp4yh

Comment: @MattBusche is right. Switch the arguments in listFind(). `<option value="#k#" <cfif #listfindnocase(getproducts.ptype,k)#>selected</cfif>>#k#</option>`  or you can do it like `<option value="#k#" #(listfindnocase(getproducts.ptype,k) ? "selected" : "")#>#k#</option>` will work for cf9 and above.

Comment: no dude, it is still not working, no it does not show even selected .

Comment: Is the `Listlen(getproducts.ptype)` before the selectbox giving you the expected result?

Comment: As @MattBusche suggested, `listfindnocase(getproducts.ptype,k)` will work. Also, include `cfoutput` tags around the selectbox for displaying the `#k#` values.

Comment: *getproducts.ptype also value like this: "abc,xyz"* If at all possible, do not store delimited lists. That kind of denormalized structure [suffers from a number of weaknesses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437697/sql-query-multiple-tables-with-multiple-joins-and-column-field-with-comma-seper/25437961#25437961) (error prone, difficult to query, does not scale well) and makes it difficult for the db to do it's job effectively. A better structure is to store the related values in a junction table.

Answer (score 3):

There are three things wrong with this:

```
<cfloop list="#lstFinds#" index="k" delimiters=",">
<option value="#k#" <cfif #listfindnocase(k,getproducts.ptype)#>selected</cfif>>#k#</option>
</cfloop>
```

First, as others have mentioned, in the listfindnocase function, the list comes first.

Next, the reason you are not getting the desired results after sorting out the first problem, is that getproducts.ptype is not a list.  It is the value from the first row of the query.  To get all the values in a list, use the valuelist() function.

Finally, the correct syntax for having an option selected is `selected="selected"`.  So the code block above should be this:

```
<cfloop list="#lstFinds#" index="k" delimiters=",">
<option value="#k#" 
<cfif listfindnocase(ValueList(getproducts.ptype), k)>
selected="selected"
</cfif>>#k#
</option>
</cfloop>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the asker provided the following code via a [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/tQHVp4yh)

```
<cfset lstFinds = 'abc,xyz,def,www,kkr,mon,tue,wed'>

<cfquery name="getproducts" datasource="cdfg">
    select ptype
     from
    mytable  
    where
    ID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#id#">
</cfquery>

these are coming from database column ptype of a table as: abc,wed,mon,def

<select name="sbbox" id="sbbox" class="can" multiple>
  <cfloop list="#lstFinds#" index="k" delimiters=",">
    <option value="#k#" <cfif #listfindnocase(k,getproducts.ptype)#>selected</cfif>>#k#</option>
  </cfloop>
</select>
```

I ran the following code as at cflive.net

```
<cfset lstFinds = 'abc,xyz,def,www,kkr,mon,tue,wed'>

<cfset getProducts = {pType = "abc,wed,mon,def"}>

<cfoutput><select name="sbbox" id="sbbox" class="can"  multiple>
  <cfloop list="#lstFinds#" index="k" delimiters=",">
    <option value="#k#" <cfif #listfindnocase(getproducts.ptype,k)#>selected</cfif>>#k#</option>
  </cfloop>
  </select></cfoutput>
```

When I run this code, abc, def, mon, and wed are selected. Should these not be selected, or should others be checked?

This code appears to be doing what you are asking. The only changes I made

- Changed the logic as per what Matt suggested in question comments.
- Because I don't have the data to run a query against, I setup a getProducts structure with the key "pType" and the values as Asker suggested they might be. For the purpose here, my sample struct is functionally identical to a one-row query.

Finally, is it possible that you're trying to pull this from multiple rows? You might try

```
<cfset variables.ptypes = valuelist(getproducts.ptype)>
<cfoutput><select name="sbbox" id="sbbox" class="can" multiple>
  <cfloop list="#lstFinds#" index="k" delimiters=",">
    <option value="#k#" <cfif #listfindnocase(variables.ptypes,k)#>selected</cfif>>#k#</option>
  </cfloop>
  </select></cfoutput>
```

Comment: The style attributes you added are clutter.  The guy is trying to solve a logic problem.

Comment: Yeah, it was a tiny box i was tired of scrolling in, but you're 100 right, I'll pull them out of answer. Should have before I answered.